# How can I read a file encoded in utf-16 in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, utf-16

I have to read a file encoded in UTF-16 using nodejs (in chunks because it is very large). The data from the file will go into a mongodb, so I will need to convert it into utf-8. From googling, it seems that this is just plain not supported by Node, and I will have to resort to converting the raw data from a buffer myself. But I also think there ought to be a better way and I'm just not finding it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: It should supports ucs2, which is pretty close to UTF-16.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Node supports UCS-2, the UTF-16 subset supported by JavaScript.  Try using that.

See this [pull request](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/644).

Answer (score 45):

Replace the normal `utf8` you'd have when reading a text file with `utf16le` or `ucs2`:

```
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('import.csv','utf16le')
```

or:

```
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('import.csv','ucs2')
```

Also, for anyone searching the internet: anyone getting additional � (question mark) characters appearing in a parsed file, this is probably the cause of your problem. Read the file as UTF16/UCS2 and the extra characters will disappear.

Comment: Additional notes: 'ucs2' is an alias of 'utf16le' (little-endian). You can also use 'utf16le' if that will make your intent clearer in that particular instance. `Buffer.prototype.toString()` also supports the same encoding parameters. If your source is big-endian, you need to first swap the bytes using `Buffer.prototype.swap16()` since Node.js currently doesn't have a 'utf16be' encoding.

Comment: Thanks @ates that's a good suggestion, I've updated the answer to include it.